# How to write matrix row by row with implied do loop?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

My IDE is CodeBlocks with MinGW 9.2.0.

I need a help with writing matrix row by row in textual file.

This is my simple code:

```
program matrix
 
 integer :: i, j 
 integer, dimension(2,2) :: a_mat
 
 forall( i = 1 : 2, j = 1, 2 )
    
   a_mat(i,j) = i + j

 end forall 
 
 open( unit = 15, file = 'matrix_utput.txt', action = 'write' )
  
   write(15,'(*(i2.2,1x))') ( ( a_mat(i,j), j = 1, 2 ), i = 1, 2 )
 
 close( unit = 15 )

end program matrix
```

In my `.txt` file i got this:
`02 03 03 04`
How to change format to get this:

`02 03`

`03 04`

Comment: The linked question is the opposite problem, but the solution is the same, you loop over loop using a normal do loop and us the implied loop for the individual rows.

Comment: @VladimirF Is it possible to with this kind of do loop?

Comment: Yes, with format reversion. But it is less clear and you must insert the size into the format - when it is not fixed. Maybe we can reopen the question and answer about that.

Comment: @VladimirF Can you show me how?

Comment: I spent a lot of time lookong for duplicates but missed this one. It was quite a specific problem so the answer was also quite specific. I will keep my answer undeleted because there is a small difference in reading vs. writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way is to loop in a do loop line by line as shown at [Write matrix with Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674860/write-matrix-with-fortran)

But one can also do it in an implied loop using *format reversion*.

```
 write(15,'(2(i2.2,1x))') ( ( a_mat(i,j), j = 1, 2 ), i = 1, 2 )
```

Basically, the number in front of the parenthesis must be the row length (number of columns). If you put the `*` there, it will consume the whole array. This way, it will open a new record each time the format found all its items.

Comment: One can also get rid of the trailing space, but I assumed it is not necessary.

Comment: So, just to conclude: this `'(*(1x,i2.2,:))'` can not be used for a matrix with any numbers of columns and the only way is to put the number of columns into character variable and use `//` to create `'(987(1x.i2.3))'.
Is that correct?`

Comment: If you can use an explicit loop instead of implied, you can do this with advance=no, an empty write to trigger a linefeed and atomic writes see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25714322/12150218

Comment: @Cocofalco There is no need for such things with an explicit loop as the duplicate link and the link in the answer show..

Comment: @HarryKastorp Yes, or just use the normal do loop as people normally use.

Comment: @VladimirF I was just pointing out that - No - using  a computed format statement is not the only way to do this