# How do I remove the default newline character from read and write in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, newline, trailing-newline

I am using Fortran 90 and I am trying to get the following without new line

```
do i=1,size
    read*, y(i)
end do
```

with this, I always get the stdin by using the enter key. Like this
Now, I want this without pressing the Enter key, like C++. How can I do it?

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate posts. However, I have no idea what you actually want in your point 1. Point 2 has been asked and answered before, so better not ask it here if you do not want your post to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove your point 2. Please see these duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714322/how-to-write-without-a-newline-in-fortran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984672/print-values-without-new-line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661975/suppressing-line-breaks-in-fortran-95-write-statements  And please clarify your main point.

Comment: Namely, if you do not want to press Enter, how is the program supposed to find out that you finished typing your number? How do you do it in your C++?

Comment: I think what you want to know is very different from the question you 've asked.  Are you asking how to process input from the keyboard immediately, without buffering, without requiring "enter"?  C++ can't do that, either.  It requires terminal magic that is operating-system specific.  Which operating system are you targeting?

Comment: @VladimirF You can use space instead of enter key to have seperate inputs in c++

Comment: You can do the same in Fortran. You can use spaces or commas. But you must somehow terminate your input line. In both Fortran and in C++. Perhaps it will be best to show us a C++ example so that we can see what you are actually doing.

Comment: With `read*, y(i)` you are explicitly asking for each item to be on a new line. Perhaps you are simply after `read*, y(1:size)` (outside the loop) and you can split them over as many lines as you like? It's not clear that's what you mean, so please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.